# Animation doesn't affect root bone, althought I can move it around

Tags: animation, bones

I have made a mesh controlled by one root bone, I can move it around and set Keyframes, but the thing wont animate..! What have I done wrong?
And another problem: It seems to be impossible to set the origin of the armature so the transform panel in n-menue is zero zero zero, when the origin is in zero zero zero. (that would make it easyer to animate for me)

Greez Lu

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx08abxowgBzX2RNVWsxX1VzU1k/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Ok I dont really know what I did.. I started making every "in Body Action"  single user and tried to delete loose actions i didnt use and then it worked..

Comment: I wish I knew what you did do as I'm trying to animate the root bone but can't.